# Loop over a list of tuples returning just some indexes inside list comprehension

Tags: python, list, tuples

Let's say I have a list of tuples:

```
myList = [(1,2,3) , (2,3,4) , (3,4,5) ,(4,5,6) , (1,3,5) , (2,4,6)]
```

I want to iterate over it, but just gonna use the first two indexes of each tuple.

So I'd be actually iterating over:

```
[(1,2) , (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (1,3), (2,4)]
```

I know I can do this:

```
for item in myList
```

And then in my code just use `item[0], item [1]`, but I think this will really affect the readbility of my code.

But I have this `for` in a list comprehension so (I think) I can't store those values in other variable.

My question here is: Would using a dummy variable like:

```
for (variablename1,variablename2,dummyvar) in myList
```

be the best way to do that or there is a direct way to return only the first indexes from the `for`?!

(I accept hints to better clarify the question ;) )

Comment: May be you can use a throw away variable `_`

Comment: do you mean `new_list = [(a,b) for a,b, _ in mylist]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the anonymouos variable `_` is typical in such cases:

```
for x, y, _ in myList:
    # do stuff with x and y
```

If the tuples have various lengths, you can do:

```
for x, y, *_ in myList:
    # do stuff with x and y
```

to avoid errors.

Comment: So this is almost like creating a dummy variable, right? But I don't have acces to it?! Or is it like I'm already telling I won't use the third index?!

Comment: Not exactly. You could access the variable like any other, but it is a convention to signal to yourself (and co-workers) "I'm not using it".